# The right way to check url paramater using isset

Tags: php, get, isset

i was create a script to active user registration but there's a problem with my isset logic. and here's my code:

```
if (!isset($_GET['x']) || !isset($_GET['y'])) {


            echo "Check your email for activation code";

        }else{
        //collect values from the url
            $memberID = trim($_GET['x']);
            $active = trim($_GET['y']);


            if(is_numeric($memberID) && !empty($active)){

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET active = 'Yes'
    WHERE id = :memberID AND active = :active");

                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':memberID' => $memberID,
                    ':active' => $active
                ));

                //if the row was updated redirect the user
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){

                    //redirect to login page
                    header('Location: login.php?action=active');
                    exit;

                } else {

                    echo "Your account could not be activated.";

                }

            }
        }
```

but if i give code like this in url active.php?x=&y=9b4f0 or active.php?x=777&y= it show nothing. how can i handle this situation?

Comment: @AlpineCoder it just a same, there's nothing changing even if i chenge $_get to $_GET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (!isset($_GET['x']) || !isset($_GET['y'])) {`

Should work.

Comment: It work, but i still have a problem, what if i put this in my url active.php?x=38&y= it give no warning do you know how i could handle this?

Comment: `if (!isset($_GET['x']) || !strlen($_GET['x']) || !isset($_GET['y']) || !strlen($_GET['y'])) {` Should work.

Answer (score 0):

try this.,

```
if (!isset($_GET['x']) && !isset($_GET['y'])){
```

Comment: well AlpineCoder is already give the right answer and this is my other question before. if i write this it will make the logic isn't correct if X or Y is empty. thanks anyway.